# How can I get a directory from a Uri

Tags: .net

For example, if I have

> http://www.example.com/mydirectory/myfile.aspx

How can I get

> http://www.example.com/mydirectory

I am looking for a .NET function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property but it isn't too hard to parse it out:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/mydirectory/myfile.aspx");
string[] parts = uri.LocalPath.Split('/');
if(parts.Length >= parts.Length - 2){
     string directoryName = parts[parts.Length - 2];
}
```

Comment: check Rubens Farias' answer below as it is far better than this one.

Answer (score 47):

Try this (without string manipulation):

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://www.example.com/mydirectory/myfile.aspx?id=1");
Uri directory = new Uri(baseAddress, "."); // "." == current dir, like MS-DOS
Console.WriteLine(directory.OriginalString);
```

Comment: I had something very similar, but I like this much, better since it has one less function call!

Comment: Really nice method! If the base address is a directory you need to use ".." instead of ".". Also, in that case, be careful because no exception will occur if you try to get the parent of the root directory; you just get the same Uri back.

Comment: This works but is still very mysterious to me. [The docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91(v=vs.110).aspx) that in `new Uri( Uri baseUri, string relativeUri )` constructor the second argument is **The relative URI to add to the base URI**, which does not correlate with this example... what am I missing?

Answer (score 15):

Here's a pretty clean way of doing it. Also has the advantage of taking any url you can throw at it:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/mydirectory/myfile.aspx?test=1");
var newUri = new Uri(uri, System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(uri.AbsolutePath));
```

NOTE: removed Dump() method. (It's from LINQPad which was where I was verifying this!)

Comment: What does Dump() do? This solution does not compile here.

Comment: Works well without the Dump() call though. +1 for having a nice clean solution that works for every url (even without a filename).

Comment: Erm....haha silly testing ground statements! Dump() is an internal method for LINQPad which is where I usually test things before posting them!

Answer (score 0):

What about simple string manipulation?

```
public static Uri GetDirectory(Uri input) {
    string path = input.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
    return new Uri(path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf('/')));
}

// ...
newUri = GetDirectory(new Uri ("http://www.example.com/mydirectory/myfile.aspx"));
// newUri is now 'http://www.example.com/mydirectory'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're sure a filename is on the end of the URL the following code will work.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

Uri u = new Uri(@"http://www.example.com/mydirectory/myfile.aspx?v=1&t=2");

//Ensure trailing querystring, hash, etc are removed
string strUrlCleaned = u.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path); 
// Get only filename
string strFilenamePart = Path.GetFileName(strUrlCleaned); 
// Strip filename off end of the cleaned URL including trailing slash.
string strUrlPath = strUrlCleaned.Substring(0, strUrlCleaned.Length-strFilenamePart.Length-1);

MessageBox.Show(strUrlPath); 
// shows: http://www.example.com/mydirectory
```

I added some junk to the querystring of the URL to prove it still works when parameters are appended.